# Does Spring MVC support JSR 311 annotations?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs, jsr311

While helping out someone else, I noticed they were trying to do Spring development using the `@GET`, `@Consumes`, and `@Path` annotations.  It is my understanding that these annotations come from the JSR-311 specification.

I simply suggested that they use the Spring `@RequestMapping` annotation for mapping endpoints to their controller, but it made me curious as to whether or not Spring MVC (any version) supports JSR 311?

Comment: You could send in a patch so it does, touche! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312671/why-isnt-there-a-headless-bdd-testing-engine-like-rubys-capybara-for-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**. To quote [Juergen Hoeller](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/08/spring-2.5-ii-spring-mvc#view_31028):

> We're considering integration with JAX-RS on a separate basis - separate from Spring MVC's own endpoint model -, possibly supporting the use of Jersey (the JAX-RS RI) with Spring-style beans in a Spring web application context. This might make Spring 3.0 as well, depending on the finalization of JSR 311 and Jersey in time for Spring 3.0 RC1. Otherwise it would be a candidate for Spring 3.1.

However I haven't found such a support neither in 3.0 nor in 3.1.

Of course you can integrate frameworks like Apache CXF and use standard JSR-311 annotations. Spring MVC itself does not recognize these annotations.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you 'just know' this or does Spring explicitly state somewhere their reasons? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I added the best source I could find.