# Why isn't there a headless BDD testing engine like ruby's capybara for java?

Tags: java, capybara, web-testing

Why isn't there a java version of ruby's capaybara ( https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara ) that would work with tomcat or something?

I know we have selenium but it is very slow and it requires a browser to fireup.

Is there a technical reason for this?  Or it does exist?

I'm hoping there is something to speed of browser integration testing for java, spring mvc application.

Comment: Because you haven't written it yet.

Comment: SO is a little like jeopardy in that the questions have to be form in a certain way. "why there isn't something" is not a very good question, "is there a something" is :)

Comment: capaybara and cucumber is slow on Ruby too. Very slow. I don't know how Selenium is slow, but ruby's capybara+cucumber is very very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is an option that works for you