# Use REST in Spring without MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I want to use REST in Spring without using MVC framework, but it seems they encourage using it with controllers only!

Can I do so without using controllers ?? Is it advisable ?

Comment: I am looking for a Spring framework solution only. Don't want to use Jersey, restlet, reateasy etc.

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Data also?

Comment: @EllyGayle: What's wrong with using "controllers only"?  It's a Spring-only solution like you want, and does the job.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Rest services without spring-mvc using Jersey.

official : http://jersey.java.net/

examples: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

[Jersey w/ Spring 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185640/jersey-w-spring-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JAX-RS in concert with Spring](http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs) if you like, if you want to avoid using Spring for web-layer stuff.